# How do I calculate conditional probabilty with a markov chain?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

Currently I am learning about markov chains. I am struggeling with a problem, which is beautifully explained in the first answer of this post:

[Forming the transition matrix for Markov chain, given a word description of transition probabilities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587559/forming-the-transition-matrix-for-markov-chain-given-a-word-description-of-tran).

However, in addition I want to know the following:

> Suppose that it has rained neither yesterday nor the day before
> yesterday. What is the probability that it will rain tomorrow?

I made the relevant transitions bold, because the $0.6$ goes from NNY to NYY, and the $0.2$ goes from NNN to NNY.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0.8 & 0.2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0.4 & 0.6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.6 & 0.4 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0.4 & 0.6 \\
0.6 & 0.4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0.4 & 0.6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \textbf{0.6} & 0.4 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \textbf{0.2} & 0.8 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

From the problem statement I understand that I need to find the probability that it will rain tomorrow given that there was no rain yesterday and no rain the day before yesterday.

The struggle is that each probablity is conditioned on the probability of the initial state:

$$
\mathbb{P}\left(X_{n+1}=j \mid X_n=i\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(X_1=j \mid X_0=i\right)=P_{i j}
$$

And that is not the condition on which we want the final answer to be conditioned.

Assuming that each state is equally likely with $\mathbb{P} = \frac{1}{8}$, we can find the joint probability $\mathbb{P}\left(X_{n+1}=NNY, X_n=NYY\right)$ by multiplying the transition probability with the probability of the initial state:

$\mathbb{P}\left(X_{n+1}=NYY, X_n=NNY\right) = 0.6 * \frac{1}{8} = \frac{3}{40}$

We also do this for find the other joint probability:

$\mathbb{P}\left(X_{n+1}=NNY, X_n=NNN\right) = 0.2 * \frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{40}$

If we add these probabilities together, let

$\mathbb{P}\left(A\right)$ = $\frac{4}{40}$ with $A$ the joint event that it will rain tomorrow and that there was no rain yesterday nor rain the day before yesterday.

We know that "there was no rain yesterday nor rain the day before yesterday" makes $\frac{2}{8}$ of the states. If we define that as event $B$ we see that $\mathbb{P}\left(B\right) = \frac{1}{4}$.

If we condition the joint probability $A$ on $B$ we get $\frac{2}{5}$.

Given my knowlegde, this is the most logical outcome I could think of. Does this approach make sense? I am still a student. It would be amazing if I could receive feedback on this.

Comment: This problem doesn't specify enough information to know the probability of being in a NNY state, or the probability of being in a NNN state.  For example,  you could just declare that you are in a NNY pattern, and that wouldn't contravene any of the information given in the problem.  You could "cheat" and assume the probability at the steady state, but that is still assuming info not provided by the problem.

Comment: Thanks @danielV for the quick reply. I was not aware of the fact that this crucial information was missing. You are writing about "being in a NNY" pattern. Is that the same as being in a state? If with the exercise was given that it is equally likely to be in each state/pattern. How would that change your answer?

Comment: If you added the assumption that the probability in being in NNY and NNN are equal for the time the probability is being calculated, then the solution is trivially $0.5 \times 0.6 + 0.5 \times 0.2$